# Android activity back button going back to previous activity but no data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities SignIn (LAUNCHER), Main, StockTake (parent activity: Main).

Android Manifest below:

```
<application
    ......
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">          
    </activity>       
    <activity android:name=".activities.SignInActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.StockTakeActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

From Main Activity the user input data and move to the stocktake activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, StockTakeActivity.class);        
startActivity(intent);
```

In the StockTake activity 'back' button is visible on top left corner in actionbar. When the back button '<-' is press the application is going to the Main activity, but the main activity screen is cleared from user input.

In StockTake activity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I have the onSave... and onRestore... implemented. The onRestore is not been called.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);        
    savedInstanceState.putString(PART_NUMBER_KEY, String.valueOf(txtPartNumber.getText()));
    savedInstanceState.putString(PART_DESCRIPTION_KEY, String.valueOf(txtPartDescription.getText()));
   ....
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);        
    String partNumber = savedInstanceState.getString(PART_NUMBER_KEY);
    String partDescription = savedInstanceState.getString(PART_DESCRIPTION_KEY);
    .....
}
```

What do i need to do to retain user input in Main activity when the user press the '<-' back button? I am on android 6 API 23.

Comment: You'll have to set data on that component (i.e. edittext) on onResume() method of MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try shared preferences to store the data and when you come back you retrieve them.
**Initialization**

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
```

**Add content to the code**

```
editor.putString("name,"xyz");
```

**Use it when you need it**

```
sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String lanSettings = sharedpreferences.getString("name", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"` from the manifest file and add this in `StockTakeActivity`

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up removing android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity" from the manifest file and made the change below to onOptionsItemSelected(...)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```